# Tftp file transfer via serial port

Tags: serial-port, busybox, tftp

First , please excuse me for my very thin knowledge with Linux, just getting to learn it in work.

So my question is if I can transfer files from my Linux machine which runs busybox using tftp over serial port. I know how to tftp with telnet over wifi, but I'm feeling that I get a lot of errors because I'm running iPerf simultaneously. So I thought maybe tftp will be more stable via serial port.

Comment: What devices are are at each end of the serial connection?

Comment: The AP is embedded Linux and PC at the other end

Comment: Do you know the speed of the serial port on the AP? This would normally be in the documentation if it's a commercial product. Also is there a login sequence used by the AP on its serial port, or are you immediately given a command line interpreter?

Comment: 115200 , with others speeds I cant get the CLI , after enetring user/pass I get the CLI from there I switching to shell

Comment: One option is to use the [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging) command from the PC to connect to the serial port, turn on logging, and run commands on the AP to display the log files. This is easy for one-off retrievals, but longer term Celada's answer is the way to go. See if your AP has the sx, sb, or sz commands.

Answer (score 2):

[TFTP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1350.txt) is a protocol that runs over UDP/IP, so you need an IP network. A serial port by itself does not provide an IP network. To provide IP over a serial port, you have to run a protocol such as PPP.

> how to tftp with telnet over wifi

TFTP and telnet are two separate protocols that run over IP and have nothing to do with each other. I don't know what you mean by running "tftp with telnet".

In any case, if your alternatives are between wifi and PPP over a serial port, you are probably much better off with wifi: it will be much faster because a serial port will usually only go up to 115200bps.

If all you've got is a serial port and you want to transfer a file, especially is busybox is involved and you need "stability" (not sure what stability problems you are experiencing?) then honestly XModem and ZModem will be much better options that running PPP and TFTP on top of that. Certainly it will be a lot easier to set up...

Comment: Sorry for the newbie stuff that I wrote, for the TFTP with telnet I meant, that I open a telnet connection to the AP , then I can TFTP a log file from it to my pc. I'm really doubt that the software guys built a support for XModem or ZModem , I'll ask about it. Is there any other way to transfer files over serial port ? The stability I mentioned I think is related to the fact that while i'm running iPerf and at the same time I'm trying to transfer the log file with tftp I get an error after runnig "tftp ip" . If I'm stopping iPerf or reducing the traffic than TFTP works fine.

Comment: If you run iPref at the same time and it is detrimental to the TFTP session and that is over wifi, it will only go worse over a much slower serial link. There are other ways to transfer files over a serial port but they are all dedicated serial file transfer protocols like XModem and Kermit or else the solution is to run IP over the serial line first with PPP or SLIP. Anyway, if this is an AP (a wifi AP) I doubt you're going to get anywhere with the serial port. Serial ports of appliances like that are usually only for low-level diagnostics and recovery.